# how does "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" work in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I developed a BarcodeScanner app with ZXING library. for that I downloaded the complete library and added it to my proj and called an Intent with URI:"com.myproject.vinscan.client.android.SCAN". but later I found that, instead of downloading and including all packages of ZXING into our proj, we can just use the URI for Inetnt as "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN". My doubt is, how is it working without the libraries. It is working even in offline mode(without WIFI/GPRS). are the libraries included in the android SDK itself?

Comment: it works only if you have already installed the barcode scanner app from Google play, otherwise it will not work

Comment: By using `intentIntegrator`, the apps will find zxing barcode scanner by it self, if the phone doesn't installed zxing barcode scanner, it will automatic ask for it, so if the phone already installed zxing barcode scanner, it can works offline

Comment: Calling:

    Intent startIntent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    startIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(startIntent, "Choose QR Scanner"), 0);

will show a dialog to choos your scanner app, or it displays a message if you don`t have a scanner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are accessing it via the intent, as `com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` it needs the Barcode Scanner application **to be installed** on the client. (**[Reference](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent)**)

If it isn't installed, it redirects to the website and prompts the user to download. So strictly speaking, the user will have to be connected to the internet atleast once, in order to download the Barcode Scanner application (if he doesn't already have it)

---

**Alternately**

If you were to add a reference to the ZXing core library, into your project, you will be able to access it without having to direct the user out, to download Barcode Scanner.

Comment: bear in mind however that forcing a user to install an additional app mostly unrelated to your app is generally a bad idea