# Error with ZXing

Tags: java, android, zxing

Good Morning, I am new to ZXing, When I run my application get the following error:

Exception Ljava / lang / NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing ICOM / google / zxing / client / android / CaptureActivity;

My code is :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Someone could help me with this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have the barcode scanner app installed?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to include the code in `android/` in your app, including the manifest entries. You don't need to do this, and in fact should not. Remove that and see the answer about Intents below, which is what you are really doing.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to integrate [zxing](/questions/tagged/zxing) is to use their small library.
Here: [IntentIntegrator.java](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) and [IntentResult.java](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java) 
It correctly handles for you many details, such as setting category, flags, picking the most appropriate app, and most importantly handling the case where Barcode Scanner is not installed.

Another way would be to do it manually:

like [here](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent):

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 ZXing authors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.zxing.client.androidtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class ZXingTestActivity extends Activity {

  private static final String TAG = ZXingTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  private static final String PACKAGE_NAME = ZXingTestActivity.class.getPackage().getName();
  private static final Pattern SEMICOLON = Pattern.compile(";");

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    findViewById(R.id.get_camera_parameters).setOnClickListener(getCameraParameters);
    findViewById(R.id.scan_product).setOnClickListener(scanProduct);
    findViewById(R.id.scan_qr_code).setOnClickListener(scanQRCode);
    findViewById(R.id.scan_anything).setOnClickListener(scanAnything);
    findViewById(R.id.search_book_contents).setOnClickListener(searchBookContents);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_url).setOnClickListener(encodeURL);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_email).setOnClickListener(encodeEmail);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_phone).setOnClickListener(encodePhone);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_sms).setOnClickListener(encodeSMS);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_contact).setOnClickListener(encodeContact);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_location).setOnClickListener(encodeLocation);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_hidden_data).setOnClickListener(encodeHiddenData);
    findViewById(R.id.encode_bad_data).setOnClickListener(encodeBadData);
    findViewById(R.id.share_via_barcode).setOnClickListener(shareViaBarcode);
    findViewById(R.id.run_benchmark).setOnClickListener(runBenchmark);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_about) {
      int versionCode;
      String versionName;
      try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
        versionCode = info.versionCode;
        versionName = info.versionName;
      } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored) {
        versionCode = 0;
        versionName = "unknown";
      }
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      builder.setTitle(
          getString(R.string.app_name) + ' ' + versionName + " (" + versionCode + ')');
      builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.about_message));
      builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_button, null);
      builder.show();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (result != null) {
      String contents = result.getContents();
      if (contents != null) {
        showDialog(R.string.result_succeeded, result.toString());
      } else {
        showDialog(R.string.result_failed, getString(R.string.result_failed_why));
      }
    }
  }


  private final Button.OnClickListener getCameraParameters = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      String stats = collectStats();
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "zxing-external@google.com");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Camera parameters report");
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stats);
      intent.setType("text/plain");
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener runBenchmark = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setClassName(ZXingTestActivity.this, BenchmarkActivity.class.getName());
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener scanProduct = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZXingTestActivity.this);
      integrator.addExtra("SCAN_WIDTH", 800);
      integrator.addExtra("SCAN_HEIGHT", 200);
      integrator.addExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 3000L);
      integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE", "Custom prompt to scan a product");
      integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener scanQRCode = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZXingTestActivity.this);
      integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener scanAnything = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZXingTestActivity.this);
      integrator.initiateScan();
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener searchBookContents = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SEARCH_BOOK_CONTENTS");
      intent.putExtra("ISBN", "9780441014989");
      intent.putExtra("QUERY", "future");
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeURL = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      encodeBarcode("TEXT_TYPE", "http://www.nytimes.com");
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeEmail = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      encodeBarcode("EMAIL_TYPE", "foo@example.com");
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodePhone = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      encodeBarcode("PHONE_TYPE", "2125551212");
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeSMS = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      encodeBarcode("SMS_TYPE", "2125551212");
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeContact = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Jenny");
      bundle.putString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "8675309");
      bundle.putString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "jenny@the80s.com");
      bundle.putString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "123 Fake St. San Francisco, CA 94102");
      encodeBarcode("CONTACT_TYPE", bundle);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeLocation = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putFloat("LAT", 40.829208f);
      bundle.putFloat("LONG", -74.191279f);
      encodeBarcode("LOCATION_TYPE", bundle);
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeHiddenData = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(ZXingTestActivity.this);
      integrator.addExtra("ENCODE_SHOW_CONTENTS", false);
      integrator.shareText("SURPRISE!");
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener encodeBadData = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      encodeBarcode(null, "bar");
    }
  };

  private final Button.OnClickListener shareViaBarcode = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SHARE"));
    }
  };

  private void showDialog(int title, CharSequence message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    builder.show();
  }

  private void encodeBarcode(CharSequence type, CharSequence data) {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.shareText(data, type);
  }

  private void encodeBarcode(CharSequence type, Bundle data) {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.addExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);
    integrator.shareText(data.toString(), type); // data.toString() isn't used
  }

  private static String getFlattenedParams() {
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
    if (camera == null) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
      if (parameters == null) {
        return null;
      }
      return parameters.flatten();
    } finally {
      camera.release();
    }
  }

  private static String collectStats() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(1000);

    result.append("BOARD=").append(Build.BOARD).append('\n');
    result.append("BRAND=").append(Build.BRAND).append('\n');
    result.append("CPU_ABI=").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append('\n');
    result.append("DEVICE=").append(Build.DEVICE).append('\n');
    result.append("DISPLAY=").append(Build.DISPLAY).append('\n');
    result.append("FINGERPRINT=").append(Build.FINGERPRINT).append('\n');
    result.append("HOST=").append(Build.HOST).append('\n');
    result.append("ID=").append(Build.ID).append('\n');
    result.append("MANUFACTURER=").append(Build.MANUFACTURER).append('\n');
    result.append("MODEL=").append(Build.MODEL).append('\n');
    result.append("PRODUCT=").append(Build.PRODUCT).append('\n');
    result.append("TAGS=").append(Build.TAGS).append('\n');
    result.append("TIME=").append(Build.TIME).append('\n');
    result.append("TYPE=").append(Build.TYPE).append('\n');
    result.append("USER=").append(Build.USER).append('\n');
    result.append("VERSION.CODENAME=").append(Build.VERSION.CODENAME).append('\n');
    result.append("VERSION.INCREMENTAL=").append(Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL).append('\n');
    result.append("VERSION.RELEASE=").append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE).append('\n');
    result.append("VERSION.SDK_INT=").append(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).append('\n');

    String flattened = getFlattenedParams();
    String[] params = SEMICOLON.split(flattened);
    Arrays.sort(params);
    for (String param : params) {
      result.append(param).append('\n');
    }

    String resultString = result.toString();
    writeStats(resultString);

    return resultString;
  }

  private static void writeStats(String resultString) {
    File cameraParamsFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/CameraParameters.txt");
    Writer out = null;
    try {
      out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(cameraParamsFile), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
      out.write(resultString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Cannot write parameters file ", e);
    } finally {
      if (out != null) {
        try {
          out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.w(TAG, e);
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

[EDITED]
You need to have this Intent available:

```
com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN
```

to your app, whether this is inside your codebase of your app, or available externally as an app on your phone.

If it is an external app, you may need to see that it handles incoming intents, or that its service is running, etc...

This [reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005259/how-does-com-google-zxing-client-android-scan-work-in-android) may help.

Comment: No, this would not cause `NoClassDefFoundError`. That is not a class even.

Comment: Sorry, very true. It is an Intent or action String... which is then associated with a class, such as "CaptureActivity".

Answer (score -1):

If you happen to be using Eclipse for your Android development, make sure that the ZXing library is checked in Project Properties -> Java Build Path --> Order and Export section like below:

[image]

Otherwise they will not be included in the generated APK.

Comment: No, if you're using Intents, you do not include the target app's classes (which you don't even have in general).

Comment: @SeanOwen if his intention is to call ZXing as a _separate_ application, he would get an error stating that no Activity can handle the Intent. Instead he gets an ClassNotFound exception, it means that Android was trying to init the class in _his_ app but could not find the class, aka he's including ZXing as lib in his code. If you didn't realize it, most barcode app does not demand user to install ZXing but includes its own barcode reader most of which _are_ ZXing.

Comment: (I am the author of zxing.) The intent is to use Intents -- see the snippet. As you say, when done right, the typical error you encounter is `ActivityNotFoundException`. `ClassNotFoundError` indicates a different problem, that it's trying to reference some internal copy. If using `Intent`s, the answer is not to try to build in an internal copy.