# Calling one app from another on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

There are many ways, like barcode scan, 
[how does "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" work in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005259/how-does-com-google-zxing-client-android-scan-work-in-android)

**now I start APP A, there is a APP B in the thread now. But you can try BarCode App, if I call BarCode from APP C in this way, there is no BarCode's process in System**. Do I have to do something in APP B's setting?

App A calls App B,
In App B:

```
<activity   android:name="com.amp.act1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.amp.intent.action.INVOKE_APP"/>               
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In App A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.amp.intent.action.INVOKE_APP");
startActivityForResult(intent, R.id.CALL_VPAY_AIR);
```

Do I have to register the intent action, com.amp.intent.action.INVOKE_APP, somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying out implicit intents?
In that case you might want to add the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category to com.amp.act1's intent-filter

> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

Source:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: It works, thanks. But how could I hide the App B's thread in system? I don't see BarCode's thread when it is called

Comment: Hm... not sure what you're trying to do here. When you call App B, you're opening it up: I'd expect to see its thread. What is BarCode, and how do you not see its thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on device running newer version of android. You might have to set exported flag to true for your activity in the manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported